# Lendo e Comparando login e senha do arquivo em C

Tags: c

Estou programando minha tela de login do sistema com a ajuda de arquivos, ou seja, salvar/ler os dados dentro de um `arquivo.txt`.

Até agora eu consegui fazer o cadastro do login e senha do usuário, porém estou lidando com vários erros na hora de ler o texto que está dentro do `.txt`, "pegar" o login e a senha digitadas anteriormente no cadastro e comparar com o login e a senha que o usuário digitou no momento quando tentou fazer o login.

Código abaixo é iniciando a parte da escrita no `login.txt`, que é o nome do meu arquivo:

```
FILE * fp; //Está em cima do main

int main () {

 fp = fopen("login.txt", "a+");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {

        printf("\nErro na criação da abertura do arquivo!");

    } else {

        /*Aqui consta o menu, para levar o usuário a outras telas, caso ele queira "Cadastrar" ou "Logar" no sistema.*/

    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Abaixo a tela de cadastro:

```
void tela_cadastro(void)
{
    printf("\n\tLOGIN........: ");
    fgets(pessoas[i].login, 100, stdin);
    __fpurge(stdin);


    printf("\n\tSENHA........: ");
    fgets(pessoas[i].senha, 100, stdin);
    __fpurge(stdin);

    //fprintf(fp, "\n************LOGIN************SENHA************\n");

    fprintf(fp, "%s", pessoas[i].login);

    fprintf(fp, "%s", pessoas[i].senha);

   // printf("\n\tLogin: %s", pessoas[i].login); // teste só pra ver se ta mostrando login
    //printf("\n\tSenha: %s", pessoas[i].senha);//teste só pra ver se ta mostrando senha

}
```

OBS: Na tela acima do cadastro, eu consigo cadastrar no `login.txt` todos os logins e senhas.

Abaixo o código da tela de login, que é onde estou tendo problema:

```
void tela_login()
{

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("login.txt", "r"); //"r" para ler o que tem no arquivo

    if (fp == NULL) {

        printf("\nO arquivo não foi aberto!");
        exit(0);

    }

    char login[100], senha[100], str[100]; //str = linha
    int tamanho=100;

    printf("\n\tLOGIN........: ");
    fgets(login, 100, stdin);
    __fpurge(stdin);


    printf("\n\tSENHA........: ");
    fgets(senha, 100, stdin);
    __fpurge(stdin);

   // printf("\nLogin: %s", login); teste p ver o que estava imprimindo
   // printf("\nSenha: %s", senha);teste p ver o que estava imprimindo

   while(fgets(str, tamanho, stdin) != EOF) {

       if ( (strcmp(str, login) == 0) && (strcmp(str, senha) == 0) ) {

            printf("\nTESTE");

        } else {

            printf("\nERRO");

        }

    }//Fim while



    fclose(fp);

}
```

Se alguém puder me mostrar a direção. Tipo, o que devo pesquisar para solucionar esse problema. Já tentei de tudo, mas eu acredito que não to conseguindo entender como a função funciona, mas já pesquisei e ainda preciso de uma explicação mais específica. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual erro está acontecendo?

Comment: Vc quer gravar o login e a senha no arquivo isso?

Comment: Gravar eu já gravei. O erro está no login. Não to entendendo como comparar um valor do login.txt com o valor digitado pelo usuário no login.

Comment: O erro ta no while da tela tela_login();

Comment: na linha 146, da um erro: comparison between pointer and integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você disse a linha, mas não sei qual é a linha 146 (não tem numeração de linhas...).

Lendo seu código, acredito que o problema esteja na linha:

```
while(fgets(str, tamanho, stdin) != EOF) {
```

O comando `fgets` retorna um `char*`, não um `int`. Esta linha deve ser reescrita substituindo `EOF` por `NULL`, pois quando não há mais dados a serem lidos do arquivo, este comando retorna `NULL`. Do contrário, ele retorna o mesmo passado no primeiro parâmetro (no caso, `str`).

Segue o código:

```
while(fgets(str, tamanho, stdin) != NULL) {
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
while(fgets(str, tamanho, stdin)) {
```

Gostaria apenas de observar que a linha após este comando não faz sentido, uma vez que você compara `str` tanto com `login` quanto com `senha`.

Comment: Ah vdd. Desculpa, nao reparei na questão da linha. Mas nessa onde você apontou mesmo que estava o erro. Muito obrigada, eu suspeitava mas procurava como solucionar o problema e não encontrava nada que eu conseguisse entender. Sua explicação me ajudou a entender aa lógica ali também. Ah sim, essa linha eu coloquei mais porque nada tava dando certo daí resolvi ir testando tudo que eu achava que dava pra colocar. Mas obrigada. Me ajudou muito. ;)